# In reactjs how to change the state of the parent, when the state of a child changes?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component AppBarRight. OnClick of a button, I have a backend function call, after that, it should make it's parent AppBar render a component MyList. Below code is not working. Please help!

```
export default  class AppBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { RenderList: false }
    this.handleRenderList = this.handleRenderList.bind(this);
  }

  handleRenderList() {
    this.setState({ RenderList: true })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AppBarLeft/>
        <AppBarRight handler={this.handleRenderList}/>
        {this.state.RenderList ? <MyList/> : null}
      </div>
    );

  }
}

export default class AppBarRight extends React.Component{
  constuctor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={success: false}
    this.handleOnClick=this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleOnClick(){
    getDetails(cred).then( (loginresp) => {
      this.setState({ success: true} );}
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <Button Onclick={this.handleOnClick}/>
    );
    {this.state.success ? this.props.handler : null}
  } 
}
```

EDIT: I corrected the typos

Answer (score 0):

There is two problem with your code. First one is there is typo error and second you have to call the callback function which is passed to the child component.

```
  export default  class AppBar extends React.Component
    {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={RenderList: false}
      this.handleRenderList=this.handleRenderList.bind(this);
    }
    handleRenderList()
    {
    this.setState({RenderList: true})
    }
     render()
    {
     return(
            <div>
                <AppBarLeft/>
                <AppBarRight handler={this.handleRenderList}/> //Typo Error
                {this.state.RenderList ? <MyList/> :null} //Typo Error
           </div>
        );

    }
    export default class AppBarRight extends React.Component
    {
     constuctor(props)
     {
      super(props);
       this.state={success: false}
       this.handleOnClick=this.handleOnClick.bind(this);
     }
     handleOnClick(){
        getDetails(cred).then( (loginresp) => {
        this.setState({ success: true} );
        this.props.handler(); //Add this line for calling the callback function for changing the parent state.
}
        }
     ...      
     render(){
     return(
     <Button onClick={this.handleOnClick}/> //Typo Error
      );
     {this.state.success ? this.props.handler : null}
     }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  `{this.state.success ? this.props.handler : null}` can I call the callback function like this?

Comment: Not Sure, you can try this {this.state.success ? this.props.handler() : null}